# options_from_collection_for_select sorting

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you sort an options field?

I have the following form in haml

```
= form_tag assign_client_path, :id => "assign_client_form" do
  %legend select partner
  %label Select the partner you wish to assign this client to
  = select_tag "partner_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Partner.all, "id", "company_name")
  = submit_tag "Assign",  :id => 'assign'
```

With the select tag, the user is selecting from a list of company names, but it is producing the list in another order, presumably that of the IDs. How do I specify alphabetical order of company_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is whatever order `Partner.all` yields, which can be either the order of insertion, or possibly something else if you use a [`default_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope).

Simply add an [`.order`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) component to your AR request.

For example:

```
Partner.order(:company_name).all
```

Or if you want to be more explicit

```
Partner.order("company_name DESC").all
```

Side note, it's usually preferable not to make database requests like this in a view. It's cleaner and easier to maintain if you move this to the controller and create an instance variable instead.